# Reverse of numpy.bincounts?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a Numpy-optimized version of inverse [`numpy.bincounts`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). I realize `bincounts` is not one-to-one, so let's talk about the simplest version.

```
import numpy as np


def bincounts_inverse(counts):
    list = []
    dtype = np.min_scalar_type(counts.shape[0] - 1)
    for bin, count in enumerate(counts):
        ar = np.empty(count, dtype=dtype)
        ar[:] = bin
        list.append(ar)

    return np.concatenate(list)
```

This is probably the best I can get with my current knowledge of Numpy and Python. It will be very fast when the the counts are high and the bins are low, but slow, when the opposite is true. It's asymptotically optimal, but probably not the best you can do.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Here is a sample input/output.

```
counts = np.array([3, 1, 0, 2, 5], np.uint8)
bincounts_inverse(counts) = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                                     dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and expected output? It would help.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'll add that to my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inverse of `bincount` would be [`repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) -

```
np.repeat(np.arange(len(counts)), counts)
```

Sample run -

```
In [22]: counts = np.array([3,0,2,1,0,2])

In [23]: list = []
    ...: dtype = np.min_scalar_type(counts.shape[0] - 1)
    ...: for bin, count in enumerate(counts):
    ...:     ar = np.empty(count, dtype=dtype)
    ...:     ar[:] = bin
    ...:     list.append(ar)
    ...: out = np.concatenate(list)

In [24]: out
Out[24]: array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5], dtype=uint8)

In [25]: np.repeat(np.arange(len(counts)), counts)
Out[25]: array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5])
```

Another with using non-zero indices and this might be more efficient with *sparsey* `counts` -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(counts!=0)
out = np.repeat(idx, counts[idx])
```